# How do I convert (latitude,longitude) into (x,y) coordinates?

Tags: c

What is the formula for real world (latitude,longitude) conversion into (x,y) coordinates?

Comment: Not until you explain what projection you use.

Comment: For Mercator projection take a look at [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection#Mathematics_of_the_projection).

Comment: can any one explain how many projection can be used for lat long measurements

Comment: as i am using the lambert projection how many are there like this one and which have the best results

Comment: why any one down vote can one explain the reason???

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Latitudes and longitudes exist on a spherical globe.
Map X and Y coordinates exist on a (theoretically) flat map.

To convert between them, you need to "project" the spherical coordinates onto the flat map.

There are many different ways to do projections.  Some are optimised for particular regions.  An earlier poster mentioned the Mercator projection.  This is a popular one, but has its limitations (as all of them do).

Stage one is probably to better understand your needs.  What sort of latitude/longitude data do you have?  What do you plan to do with it?  Is your data confined to particular regions?  What level of accuracy is needed?  Is conversion speed important?  (You may need to trade speed against accuracy).

[Wikipedia has a reasonable article on UTM (Mercator) projections.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system)

Comment: my concern is about finding the speed i need the accurate speed i can bear some error on position finding but not very much erroneous data, and yes it is for particular region that in middle east region